# can't mount /boot/efi: dependency failed

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, uefi

my ubuntu 20.04 vbox machine, with kernel 5.11.3 can't work correctly. Last friday I reboot my virtual machine, it stucks for about 1 minute halting, and then the following error message is generated ：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDepe.png)

Despite has errors , I can still got a shell, but my x11 can't work， it means I can't get a Graphic interface. so does the netcard. First time I think it may because my disk is almost full, the /dev/sda2 mounted in / is about 96% used. I delete some big file and reboot, but useless. Before asking this question, I've tried some methods, but it doesn't work.

1. I've checked blkid output and /etc/fstab file, the uuid is same enter image description here
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b9Hy.png)
2. replace the uuid in /etc/fstab with /dev/sda1 and reboot
3. I mount the /dev/sda1 in /boot/efi manully, and it does't output anything, but when I check the dh -f command, I found /dev/sda1 is not mounted. type ls -l /boot/efi, it has nothing.
4. it seems that I can mount /dev/sda1 in /mnt directory. Thanks very much for giving me some advice!